# magento2 uicomponent filter on id column on bases of text search

Tags: magento2, filter, uicomponent

I created a custom Ui-component grid having one column `customer_id`.

For Customer_id I created a `renderer` class that gets the name of customer through `customer_id`.

**uicomponennt Column**

```
        <column name="customer_id" class="Ced\CsMarketplace\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Vendoremail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Vendor Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>                                              
        </column>
```

now When i use filter for this column. it posts `customer_id`.

I want to search on `customer email-id` text.

Comment: I am also looking for similar thing

Comment: @AshishRaj You can do it by call back in your model collection file. there you can get customer_id and based on that you can write your custom logic.

Comment: yes I am able to show the customer name or email by using id but how to use filter for that fields...

Comment: Can you show me a code example... it will be great for me, thanks

Comment: @AshishRaj you can check my answer .. it might help you.

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296226

Comment: I guess you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Model Collection file you can use `_renderFiltersBefore()` method. like below i used.

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {

        $filters = $this->request->getParam('filters');
        if (isset($filters['customer_id'])) { // your filter index in which you want filter callback
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

            $customers = $objectManager->get('My\Custom\Model\MyModel')->create()
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('email', ['like' => '%' . $filters['customer_id'] . '%']);

            $customer_id = array();

            foreach ($customers as $customer) {
                $customer_id[] = $customer->getId();
                $this->getSelect()->orWhere("main_table.customer_id = '" . $customer->getId() . "'");
            }
        }
        
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```